# why outlet text disappears in Mobile while it appears in Debugging view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, interface-builder

i've some controls on viewcontrollers on stroyboard which not connected to properties or any iboutlets, when running and put app in background and return app in forground again text in buttons and uilabels disappears .

when debugs view hierarchy i found them on debugging view.

this is applied to labels and buttons inside app even inside uitableview cell even connected to iboutlet or not , with custom font or not , even with static text on story board or text from localizable file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl5j7.png)